# CMake not working - very confused - Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmake

I am trying to install a directly from Github, and the instructions say to clone it and use cd to go the directly, which I did successfully. Then, it says to type "cmake ." and then "make install". When I type `cmake .` I get this error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

Please help, I have already been searching around and looking at other stack overflow posts for a while, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I have tried removing and reinstalling cmake, but that seems to make no difference.

Comment: Have you checked other questions with the same error message? E.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629966/how-to-set-cmake-cxx-variable-on-windows